# SQL Server - convert date to weekday and count each instance of weekday in second column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Wondering how to select from a table:

```
FIELDID personID  purchaseID   dateofPurchase
--------------------------------------------------
2         13       147         2013-03-21 00:00:00
3         13       147         2013-03-23 00:00:00
4         13       456         2013-03-24 00:00:00
5         25       123         2013-03-21 00:00:00
6         25       123         2013-03-22 00:00:00
7         25       456         2013-03-21 00:00:00
8         25       456         2013-03-23 00:00:00
9         25       456         2013-03-28 00:00:00
10        25       789         2013-03-21 00:00:00
11        82       147         2013-03-22 00:00:00
12        82       456         2013-03-22 00:00:00
```

I'd like to get a result table of two columns: weekday and the number of purchases of each weekday.

So far, I have something like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateofPurchase)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Weekend' 
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday' 
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday' 
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday' 
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday' 
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday' 
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Weekend' 
    END AS 'day', 
    COUNT(dateofPurchase) AS 'dates'
FROM 
    dbo.PurchaseRecord
GROUP BY 
    dateofPurchase;
```

But this returns two Thursday rows and two weekend rows, because they are different weeks. How can I get it to only return 1 row for each Thursday and one for weekend?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
SELECT v.wkday, COUNT(*) as dates
FROM dbo.PurchaseRecord pr CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dateofPurchase) IN (1, 7)
                   THEN 'Weekend'
                   ELSE DATENAME(WEEKDAY, dateofPurchase)
              END)
     ) v(wkday)
GROUP BY dateofPurchase
GROUP BY v.wkday;
```

This uses `CROSS APPLY` to define `wkday` once, so it can be used both in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`.  Note that SQL Server has a function that returns the name of the week day.  You don't need a `CASE` expression for that.

EDIT:

If you want to count unique purchases, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT purchaseId)
```

Comment: That seems overly complicated compared to my answer

Comment: @Kevin . . . If you think that repeating a complex `case` expression is simpler, you haven't had to maintain much code then.

Comment: I would argue Gordon's answer is more inline with what SQL should look like anyway. Case Statements like that are not only ugly but facilitate hard coding to a degree as well as not being very set based.

Comment: As opposed to what appears to be an inexperienced programmer understanding and maintaining a cross-apply with two group by's?

Comment: I mean if youre new, do you really want to be taught bad practices when youre more impressionable?

Comment: @GordonLinoff this works, thanks - how can I make it so if there are two dates on the same purchase IDs, I only count it as one?

Comment: This generates a syntax error for me. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a3b6d/2

Comment: I just removed the last group by statement and it worked for me - but a new requirement I was wondering is my above comment. How, if a date from a class ID has already been counted, it won't be counted again

Comment: @DougCoats Mine does have the slight advantage of actually working, however

Comment: @Jack_Frost if there are two (or more) dates, which date should be included?

Comment: @Kevin Sorry I meant if a person purchases at least one item (Purchase ID) then that is considered a purchase date, so we don't need to count it twice if two purchases are made on the same day. 

So the result table would be 
thursday : 3
friday : 2
weekend : 3

Comment: @Kevin so for example, if the purchase ID and date of purchase are the same, only count it as one date in the result table

Comment: @DougCoats I'm not necessarily counting unique purchases, but counting unique situations when the person ID and the date are the same. So if they are the same for multiple rows, then only count one of those instead of all of them. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not necessarily counting unique purchases, but counting unique situations when the person ID and the date are the same. So if they are the same for multiple rows, then only count one of those instead of all of them. Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group by what you want, the datepart

```
    GROUP BY CASE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, dt)
    WHEN 1 THEN 'Weekend' 
    WHEN 2 THEN 'Monday' 
    WHEN 3 THEN 'Tuesday' 
    WHEN 4 THEN 'Wednesday' 
    WHEN 5 THEN 'Thursday' 
    WHEN 6 THEN 'Friday' 
    WHEN 7 THEN 'Weekend' 
    END
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps as I am no longer getting two thursdays, but I'm still getting two weekends - any idea how I can get it to be one? Is this because in the case there are two different cases for sat and sun?

Comment: why arent you labeling satruday and sunday as such?

Comment: It's a strange business requirement